# What halachic issues are involved in the use of a trouser press in the nine days?

Tags: halacha, clothing, nine-days

A [trouser press](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trouser_press) “is an electrical appliance used to smooth the wrinkles from a pair of trousers (pants in Australia, Canada, South Africa and the United States)”. [Picture is here http://store.makro.co.uk/images/PRODUCT/medium/365515.jpg](http://store.makro.co.uk/images/PRODUCT/medium/365515.jpg).

The press works on the bottom two-thirds of the trouser legs. The trousers are held between an optionally heated surface and a wooden board. Heat is typically applied for 30 mins.

What halachic issues are involved in the use of a trouser press in the nine days?
Does it make any difference if the press is used every weekday of the year?
What are the issues if the trousers are put the in the press but the heat is not applied?

Comment: Sounds like an iron to me

Comment: Sounds like something that may not be used on Shabbos during the nine days.

Comment: @GershonGold May it be used on any other Shabbos??

Comment: @DoubleAA, GershonGold was commenting on the _Shabas_ asked about. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

I found this on  [dinonline.com](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/08/01/drying-and-ironing-in-nine-days/):

> it is permitted to dry the laundry in the Nine Days. This is not
>   considered part of the laundry, and is therefore permitted. Ironing
>   the laundry, however, is forbidden, but creases can be pressed out in
>   **an unprofessional way**.

The term "unprofessional way" is vague, and, in my case, I don't really know what types of machines "professionals" use. So, I'm making some assumptions, here in my answer:

If you do a "minimal" job and press a few creases but don't leave the pants looking completely new, I think you've done an UNprofessional job, and this may be OK.

Offhand, this type of machine does not look like a machine "professionals" use. I don't think a dry cleaners uses this, but then, again, they are pressing thousands of suits and pants a week, whereas you're doing 1 or 2. Also, I have seen them use a small iron to iron a curtain or tablecloth, and it's the same type of iron used at home. So, maybe an iron is considered "professional"?

Comment: No proof (but you don't have proof either;), but my feeling is that a trouser press would classify as something that is "professional," because in my experience most people don't use trouser presses.

Comment: I asked my LOR and he said, it's like ironing (@DoubleAA) but you can put the trousers in the press and not turn on the heating element. (All talking about weekdays).

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - Thanks for your comment. Not only did I learn something about this gadget, (I assume that you own one of these?) but I also learned that I should probably shut up when I have no clue as to what I'm talking about. (I had no clue as to how this gadget really works. I still don't quite get it even after you had described it!)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - Not meaning to sound sarcastic, but why not press the pants by hanging the pants in the bathroom and running the hot shower? That's "unprofessional" and it's steaming, not ironing.